# How do I explicitly set the code editor width in Visual Studio 2013 to 80 characters?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, text-editor

***This is an IDE tools question.***

I want to adhere to a specific style guide which wants me to have my code lines wrap to the next line if they exceed 80 characters on one line. When I select the word wrap option in Visual Studio 2013 text editor, it wraps the current window width of my project. How can I explicitly change my code editor window to be 80 characters in width without having to eyeball it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [VS extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da227a0b-0e31-4a11-8f6b-3a149cf2e459/view/Reviews) to add a visual guideline at the desired number of chars, then you can break your lines as needed when you approach the line.  I'm reinstalling my laptop at the second so can't check, but I assume that the Visual Studio line-wrap option is only visually wrapping the text on your screen rather than actually breaking the line onto a subsequent line when it's over 80 (or width of screen in your case), which isn't really what the style guide you're following will be trying to get you to do.

If you had ReSharper installed, there is an option in that which allows the breaking of lines automatically at a given width.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm surprised this feature is not included in Visual Studio.

Comment: You're not the first to make that observation :)